# vue-router doesn't reset during running tests

Tags: unit-testing, vuejs2, vue-router

currently I am writing tests for Vue.js app and got stuck with the problem: if there are some tests for routing, paths in `href` are modified in each next test according to previous ones.

For example, if in first test I simulate click on a link with `href='document/123'` and check the `vm.$router.history.path`, it will correctly show `document/123`, but if in the next test I'll try to do the same, `vm.$router.history.path` will show `document/document/123` and keep adding 'document' in path with every next test.

It is strange and looks like `router` keeps existing during all tests in `describe` block even though I have `beforeEach` hook where I re-initialize *Vue* and usage of all plugins alongside with *Vue-router* and in `afterEach` hook I call `$destroy()` method on *Vue* instance.

Is there any way to modify or reset `vm.$router.history` object or its properties in `afterEach` hook or am I missing something else?

Here is code of the test:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Search from '../../../src/Search.vue';
import router from '../../../src/router';

describe('Search', () => {
   let vm;

   beforeEach((done) => {
     const container = document.createElement('div');
     vm = new Vue({
        router,
        render: h => h(Search),
     }).$mount(container);
     done();
   });

   afterEach((done) => {
     vm.$destroy();
     done();
   });

   it('should navigate to single page when user clicks on "More" button', (done) => {
     let moreButton = vm.$el.querySelector('.btn');
     let clickEvent = new window.Event('click');
     moreButton.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
     Vue.nextTick().then(() => {
       expect(vm.$router.history.current.path).to.equal('/document/1548'); // passes
       done();
     });
   });

  it('should navigate to single page when user clicks on document title', (done) => {
     let link = vm.$el.querySelector('h6 a');
     let clickEvent = new window.Event('click');
     link.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
     Vue.nextTick().then(() => {
       expect(vm.$router.history.current.path).to.equal('/document/1548'); // fails, actual path is /document/document/1548
       done();
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: Found a small workaround, but it doesn't look like the best solution: either in `afterEach` or at the end of each test use `vm.$router.push('/')` to go back to "home"

Answer (score 1):

Old question but incase others are encountering the same issue, the solution is described here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-test-utils/issues/1681

Specifically change the 'mode' parameter in your test suite to 'abstract'. Otherwise the route will be based on window.location which is preserved between tests. 'abstract' configures navigation to be based on the 'stack' which is instantiated with new instances of vue-router.

Locally I had to parameterize my instantiation of vue-router so that in production mode 'history' was used and when running the test suite 'abstract' was used.